# first realm db can be open encrypted but writeCopyToPath cannot

Tags: realm

I'm using Realm 0.98.6 with Xcode 7.3 in an OSX app to create an encrypted realm database and then making a clean copy to place in my bundle. The original database opens with the Realm Browser (after pasting in the key), but the copy does not.

Here is the code I use to create both the databases. There are no writes in the routines called, just a mix of `realm.add`s and `realm.append`s to create a collection of related objects:

```swift
let config = Realm.Configuration(path: realmTempFile, encryptionKey: key)
let realm = try! Realm(configuration: config)

try! realm.write {
    loadAuthors(authorFile, realm: realm)
    loadVolumes(volumesFile, realm: realm)
}

try! realm.writeCopyToPath(realmFile, encryptionKey: key)
```

If I remove the `encryptionKey` parameters from the `config` and `writecopy`, then both databases open ok with the Realm Browser.

In case it matters, I'm deleting the db files with the Finder (and associated lock files) before each attempt. (*I've also tried changing the names to mitigate any temporary files hanging around.*). The only obvious difference between the two files is 7.5 vs 6.9 MB filesize for the 'original' and 'copy' respectively (i.e., as expected the copy is slightly smaller).

I'd love some suggestions! It's a pretty vanilla program of <400 lines that loads a db for later use in an iOS & Android app. I can always ship the bigger file, but it's making me wary of what else I might not know... thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of the Realm Browser are you using? Make sure you're using Realm Browser 0.98.6: https://github.com/realm/realm-browser-osx/releases/tag/0.98.6

Comment: Away from computer , but I'm pretty sure the realm browser was the latest as I updated it just a few hours before to get the export Java Model with Primary Key fix. Also, I could not open the copied db from swift code either - using the same key of course.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Realm Browser 0.98.6.

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue but couldn't. Could you please take a look at my sample project to see if it works for you? http://static.realm.io/debug/EncryptedRealmCopy.tgz If that works, I'd appreciate if you could adapt it to exhibit the bug you're experiencing so I can look more into this.

Comment: @jpsim I took a quick look at this. Is it important for me to have the `db.realm` file referenced in the tgz or should I just create my own? (Is there some other way for us to communicate on this?)

Comment: No, the db.realm is automatically created (and in fact, removed at the start of the project if present, to ensure a clean slate)

Comment: Feel free to communicate with me over email instead: help@realm.io

Comment: Did you make any progress on this @mm2001?

Comment: I took a look at your example and of course it runs just fine. I'd like to say it's something about my data exposing some strange but deep bug, but I haven't had a chance to (dis)prove that yet :). I should get to it tomorrow with a bit of luck and will let you know for sure (as I'd like to ship that app this week with a 10% smaller db if possible!). Thx for the follow-up.

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up! I appreciate it!

Comment: Sent an email to help@realm.io. Latest theory: my code above is immediately followed by `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`. Perhaps realm is still writing the file and doesn't complete before the app is terminated?

Comment: It's possible that this issue is the same as https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3194